# Cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *const' with an rvalue of type 'const int *'

Tags: c++, pointers, variables, constants

Why I have the error for the following code:

```
const int r = 3;
int *const ptr = &r;
```

However it works normaly if I define r as a plain int. As I understand, the second line only defines the pointer ptr as a const, which means that the value of this pointer cannot be changed. But why I a const pointer cannot point to a const int?

Comment: According to the book Cpp Primer 5th Ed. The simple trick is to read it inside-out. A `const int *ptr = &r;` can be read as a pointer that points to a constant integer. However, `int *const ptr = &r;` can be read as a constant pointer that points to an integer. In your case `r` is a constant integer but the pointer needs to point to an integer. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @programmingRage Yes it helps! thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) says that the definition

```
int *const ptr = &r;
```

makes `ptr` a constant pointer to **non-constant** `int`.

That is, while the variable `ptr` itself can't be modified (you can't assign to `ptr`), what it points to can. And that doesn't match the type of `r` which is constant.

If you want a constant pointer to a constant int you need:

```
int const* const ptr = &r;
```

Now neither the variable `ptr` can be modified, nor the data it points to.

Comment: Well, I prefer to write `const int *const ptr = &r;`. Is there a difference between these 2 styles?

Comment: @ProgrammingRage `const int` is an integer which is constant, and `int const` is a constant integer. No difference. :)